# Mac OS X (10.9.2) Terminal: Getting Weird Characters ~$â

Tags: terminal, internationalization

out of nowhere I am getting the following weird characters:

$â followed by a paragraph sign. See the below image for more detail:

[image]

Also note where the white cursor is: it's basically 'one-off' so it's tough to tell where the cursor actually is, and becomes quite frustrating when typing.

I generally work with Ruby on Rails and have NOT added anything recently out of the ordinary. This just started happening out of the blue.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `echo $PS1` show?

Comment: Could you check or change the User name ?

Answer (score 1):

Mark, you are 100% right! I have no idea how those characters got into my /.bash_profile, but they did! So I just went in there and removed them and now all is working correctly. Thanks again!